# Jquery Calculator keeps returning NaN

Tags: jquery, calculator

Hi I have a Jquery Calculator but it keeps returning NaN

Can anyone help please

I did read some other stack over flow questions regarding similar issues and saw people were saying to put a parseInt into the jquery, which I have tried but still get NaN

Please note, I also have conditional logic (which does work) but to save putting 100's lines of code which is unrelated to my question I shortened it all.

The user would only be able to select one of the drop down options not both.

```js
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Calculator
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
$(function() {
  $("select.cover_question10").on("change", calc);
  $("select.cover_question15").on("change", calc);

  function calc() {
    var basePrice = 0;
    newPrice = basePrice;

    $("select.cover_question10 option:selected, select.cover_question15").each(function() {
      newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    });

    var percentage = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function() {
      percentage += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    });
    newPrice = newPrice + (newPrice * percentage / 100);
    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
    $("#price").val(newPrice);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>How long do you want the cover 10?</label>
<select class="select cover_question10" name="cover_question10" id="cover_question">
  <option id="cover" value="Select">Select cover</option>
  <option id="cover_12" value="cover_12" data-price="90.76" data-capacity="12 Months Cover">12 Months Cover </option>
  <option id="cover_24" value="cover_24" data-price="124.50" data-capacity="24 Months Cover">24 Months Cover</option>
  <option id="cover_36" value="cover_36" data-price="135" data-capacity="36 Months Cover">36 Months Cover</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<label>How long do you want the cover 15?</label>
<select class="select cover_question15" name="cover_question15" id="cover_question">
  <option id="cover" value="Select">Select cover</option>
  <option id="cover_12" value="cover_12" data-price="104.26" data-capacity="12 Months Cover">12 Months Cover </option>
  <option id="cover_24" value="cover_24" data-price="145.50" data-capacity="24 Months Cover">24 Months Cover</option>
  <option id="cover_36" value="cover_36" data-price="195" data-capacity="36 Months Cover">36 Months Cover</option>
</select>
<br><br> £

<span id="item-price">0.00</span>
```

Also here is my Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/0ajo48ne/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selected the selected option on one selectbox but the selectbox itself on the other. This resulted in 1 `data-pirce` attribute to always be `undefined`. When correcting it. Also added a if statement to check if a valid value was set.

```js
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Calculator
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
$(function() {
  $("select.cover_question10").on("change", calc);
  $("select.cover_question15").on("change", calc);

  function calc() {
    var basePrice = 0;
    newPrice = basePrice;

    $("select.cover_question10 option:selected, select.cover_question15 option:selected").each(function() {
      console.log();
      if(/^[\.\d]+$/.test($(this).data('price'))) {
        newPrice += parseFloat($(this).data('price'), 10);
      }
    });

    var percentage = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function() {
      percentage += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    });
    newPrice = newPrice + (newPrice * percentage / 100);
    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
    $("#price").val(newPrice);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>How long do you want the cover 10?</label>
<select class="select cover_question10" name="cover_question10" id="cover_question">
  <option id="cover" value="Select">Select cover</option>
  <option id="cover_12" value="cover_12" data-price="90.76" data-capacity="12 Months Cover">12 Months Cover </option>
  <option id="cover_24" value="cover_24" data-price="124.50" data-capacity="24 Months Cover">24 Months Cover</option>
  <option id="cover_36" value="cover_36" data-price="135" data-capacity="36 Months Cover">36 Months Cover</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<label>How long do you want the cover 15?</label>
<select class="select cover_question15" name="cover_question15" id="cover_question">
  <option id="cover" value="Select">Select cover</option>
  <option id="cover_12" value="cover_12" data-price="104.26" data-capacity="12 Months Cover">12 Months Cover </option>
  <option id="cover_24" value="cover_24" data-price="145.50" data-capacity="24 Months Cover">24 Months Cover</option>
  <option id="cover_36" value="cover_36" data-price="195" data-capacity="36 Months Cover">36 Months Cover</option>
</select>
<br><br> £

<span id="item-price">0.00</span>
```

Comment: It still's shows `NaN` is just one options is selected.

Comment: @0stone0 I know, thats why i say both select options need to be selected. It seems likely though that both selectboxes has to be selected to come with a correct price. If not a simple if statement can fix it.

Comment: Hi, this is very close to working, however there is a conditional logic so the user would only actually be able to see one drop down as the other is hidden and that is dependent on what they answer previous questions of my form as.

Comment: @user1348927 added check so it works with 1 selectbox aswell. See the added if statement.

Comment: Thats great! Thanks.. Is there a way so it includes the pence in the output? So if you select 12 months the data price is 90.76 but the .76 is not showing in the total price

Comment: @user1348927 You can use `parseFloat()` as long you don't need to much precision.

Answer (score 2):

```
<label>How long do you want the cover 10?</label>
<select
  class="select cover_question10"
  name="cover_question10"
  id="cover_question"
>
  <option id="cover" value="Select" data-price="0">Select cover</option>
  <option
    id="cover_12"
    value="cover_12"
    data-price="90.76"
    data-capacity="12 Months Cover"
  >
    12 Months Cover
  </option>
  <option
    id="cover_24"
    value="cover_24"
    data-price="124.50"
    data-capacity="24 Months Cover"
  >
    24 Months Cover
  </option>
  <option
    id="cover_36"
    value="cover_36"
    data-price="135"
    data-capacity="36 Months Cover"
  >
    36 Months Cover
  </option>
</select>

<br /><br />
<label>How long do you want the cover 15?</label>
<select
  class="select cover_question15"
  name="cover_question15"
  id="cover_question"
>
  <option id="cover" value="Select" data-price="0">Select cover</option>
  <option
    id="cover_12"
    value="cover_12"
    data-price="104.26"
    data-capacity="12 Months Cover"
  >
    12 Months Cover
  </option>
  <option
    id="cover_24"
    value="cover_24"
    data-price="145.50"
    data-capacity="24 Months Cover"
  >
    24 Months Cover
  </option>
  <option
    id="cover_36"
    value="cover_36"
    data-price="195"
    data-capacity="36 Months Cover"
  >
    36 Months Cover
  </option>
</select>
<br /><br />
£

<span id="item-price">0.00</span>



$(function () {
  $("select.cover_question10").on("change", calc);
  $("select.cover_question15").on("change", calc);

  function calc() {
    var basePrice = 0;
    newPrice = basePrice;

    $("select.cover_question10, select.cover_question15")
      .find("option:selected")
      .each(function () {
        newPrice += parseInt($(this).data("price"), 10);
      });

    var percentage = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function () {
      percentage += parseInt($(this).data("price"), 10);
    });
    newPrice = newPrice + (newPrice * percentage) / 100;
    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
    $("#price").val(newPrice);
  }
});
```

Comment: Default selected option has  no property of price, so it's returning NAN, I just updated by 10, and updated jquery selector to select child option.

Comment: Can be easily set to the default value of 0.